Elastic Search Query | Aggregation | Nested Aggregation
I have this as one of the hit inside hits while querying all data
{
  "id": "id123",
  "sc": 1,
  "src": {
    "aid": "aid123",
    "result": {      
      "cid": "cid123",
      "scm": "GL",
      "title": "DTitle",
      "reason": "DReason",
      "status": "Failed",
      "entity": "DEnt"
    },
    "createdAt": 1718864490635,
    "rel": {
      "nam": "dRel",
      "par": "pid123"
    }
  }
}


I want to aggregate them first on basis of cid,aid and retrieve latest entry per group
Then i need to aggregate on cid on the evaluated result from prev query and find total counts, passed and failed count based on status along with all field inside result

GET /index/_search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "compliance_group": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "result.cid"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "artifact_group": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "aid"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "latest_execution": {
              "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "createdAt": {
                      "order": "desc"  // Use "asc" for ascending order
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "_source": {
                  "includes": [
                    "result.cid", 
                    "aid", 
                    "result.scm",
                    "result.title",
                    "result.reason",
                    "result.entity",
                    "result.status"
                  ]
                },
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


GET /index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_complianceId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "result.cid.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "result.cid.keyword"
          }
        },
        "passed_count":{
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "result.status.keyword": "PASSED"
            }
          }
        },
        "failed_count":{
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "result.status.keyword": "FAILED"
            }
          }
        },
         "sample_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
                  "includes": [
                    "result.cid", 
                    "aid", 
                    "result.scm",
                    "result.title",
                    "result.reason",
                    "result.entity",
                    "result.status"
                  ]
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Both the queries are working fine in separation , how do i use the second aggregation on the evaluated result from first aggregation

There is no way to use query results in the same query results. Elasticsearch does not support chaining the results of one aggregation directly into another aggregation within a single query.
You should handle with it in application side

Thanks, @MusabDogan.My brain was about to explode going through documentation figuring this out

You're welcome. :) Learning is exactly works like that. Let me share it as an answer.

There is no way to use Elasticsearch query results in the same query.
Elasticsearch does not support chaining the results of one aggregation directly into another aggregation within a single query. You should handle with it in application side.
